# Arch Linux DHCP Problems

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, dhcp

I’m stuck in Arch Linux internet setup. I’m attempting to dual boot Windows 10 and Arch Linux but the part I’m getting stuck at is setting up DHCP, when I enter `dhcpcd enp3s0` console replies with

```
dhcpcd-9.4.0 starting
DUID (too much to type)
enp3s0: waiting for carrier
enp3s0: carrier acquired
enp3s0: IAID 8e:c2:a5:50
enp3s0: soliciting an IPV6 router 
enp3s0: carrier lost
```

How do I fix this and get access to the internet to finish the setup?

This may not help but I'm running the setup in bios mode.

Comment: Can you please post the content of your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?